# Does an Entity Framework Foreign Key Association Always Imply Cascade Delete?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

After reading [Foreign Keys in the Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) I tried adding a Foreign Key relationship to an EF 5 Code First application (the app uses Independent Associations to date).

I noticed that the generated DDL includes a cascade delete.  This is the opposite of the behavior with Independent Associations.

Given that a Foreign Key relationship is created in EF Code First by adding an *int* property named according to the convention *ClassnameId*, is it possible to have a non-cascading delete?  If so, what value would be assigned to *ClassnameId* to disassociate the related object without deleting it from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you explicitly declare a foreign key, that is non nullable, EF will assume that you want a cascading delete.

You can either make the Foreign key nullable:

```
public int? YourFkId {get;set;}
```

Or you can use fluent notations in your `OnModelCreating`

```
     modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>()
        .HasMany( c => c.Class2s )
        .WithRequired(x => x.Class1 )
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```